# Problema con datatable ajax laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ajax

tengop un detalle con la datatable de laravel con la libreria yajra, trato de imprimir una variable y me da error aqui mi codigo

```
$gastos = Gastos::where('empresa',Auth::user()->empresa)->where('tipo', "<>", 5)->get();

  return DataTables::of($gastos)
      ->editColumn('beneficiario', function ($gastos){
          $contacto = DB::table('contactos')->where('id',$gastos->beneficiario)->get();
          return '<a href="" target="_blanck">'.$contacto[0]->nombre.'</a>';
      })
      ->rawColumns(['beneficiario'])
      ->toJson();
```

al tratar de imprimir contacto->nombre me lanza error

Comment: Y cuál es el error?

Comment: al momento de ejecutar la ruta me sale error 500, pero es por la cuestion del contacto no se porq me marca ese error tngo rato tratando de solucionar y nada, no se si sea por el metodo de busqueda de ajax o algo

Comment: No se exactamente porque pueda estar produciendo el error, pero si veo otro error que tienes en html que seguro no permitirá que se visualice como quieres, y es donde dice `target="blanck"`, sustituyelo por `target="blank"`

Comment: Si la petición ajax que estás realizando es `post`, ¿si estás mandando el "csrf token"?

Comment: no es por medio de post, es por get.. tengo q tener toda la consulta en gastos par q me pueda funcionar. ,,